# The elements of $[0,1]$ cannot be put in an array,(sequence?). Proof.

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

The answer is given I will highlights the deduction which I don't understand:

Let's suppose the opposite:

$$a_1=0,a_{11},a_{12},a_{13}... \\ a_2=0,a_{21},a_{22},a_{23}... \\ ....$$

Lets look at the element $a^*=0.a_{11}^*a_{22}^*a_{33}^*...$ such that $a_{ii}^*=\begin{cases}0 ,a_{ii}=1 \\ 1, a_{ii}\neq1 \end{cases}$
Then $a* \in [0,1]$

The following steps are what I don't understand:

> $$\implies (\exists n) a_n=a_{i}^* \\ a_{ni}=a_{ii}^* \\ a_{nn}=a_{nn}^*$$

Then the proof concludes:

If $a_{nn}=1 \implies a_{nn}^*=0 \ a_{nn}\neq a_{nn}^*$ basically same analogy with $a_{nn}\neq 1$$\implies a_n \neq a_n^*$  contradiction.

Comment: I highlighted it in the yellow box. From $\exists n $ and so on... the detals there are unclear as to why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $a^*$ is in $[0,1]$ so it must appear in the listing somewhere. That is, there is some $n$ such that $a^* = a_n$.

Now, consider the $i$th digit of that number, for arbitrary $i$. $a^*_{ii}$ is that $i$th digit. That is also $a_{ni}$ because $a^* = a_n$. Therefore $a^*_{ii} = a_{ni}$.

Finally, specialise to $i=n$. Obtain $a^*_{nn} = a_{nn}$, which contradicts the definition of the $^*$ operation.